# Variables not being saved in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When writing a function:

```
function Manage-fullAccess
{
    Param
    ([Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
    Position=0,
    mandatory=$true)]
    $user,

    [string] [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
    Position = 1,
    mandatory=$true)]
    $mailboxName,

    [string] [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    $fullAccess
    ) 
    
    # ...
}
```

I am being prompted to provide values, but variables are not being saved. Probably some super rookie mistake, but I would need a hand here. Both $user and $mailboxName variables are **empty**

Comment: Where are you referencing them when they are empty?

Comment: @DougMaurer  when I try to type them in into Shell. So in the active session I type $user and it returns nothing.

Comment: If you set a variable inside a function it will not exist outside of it by default. Instead you should output whatever you want to use from this function as its rerun value.

Comment: There are two features that may be confusing to you.  The first is the scope of a variable.  @Olaf has pointed the way here.  The second is the fact that, when a non existent variable is referenced,  PS creates the variable, and makes it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.  The first is that you are referencing $user from the main (outer) scope,  the variable defined inside the function is out of scope.

The second is that PS does something interesting when a variable is reference, but there is no such variable in scope.  It quietly invents such a variable, and leaves it empty.

You are going to have to learn how to transfer values from inside the function to your main scope.  That's a little long for an answer here.  There is some online help about Scopes.  See the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

Adding `return $user, $mailboxName` to the end of your function is one way to solve this issue.

```
function Manage-fullAccess

{
    Param
    ([Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
    Position=0,
    mandatory=$true)]
    $user,

    [string] [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
    Position = 1,
    mandatory=$true)]
    $mailboxName,

    [string] [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    $fullAccess
    ) 
    return $user, $mailboxName
}
```